# How to set value inside control

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections

I am trying some multilingual website where I have value inside Dictionary object now I want to set those text according to my language selection.
below is my code.

Login.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LoginForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="MultiligualApplication.LoginForm" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <%
        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> dict = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>();
        string className = "ClassEnLang";
        if (Session["lang"] != null)
        {
            if (Session["lang"].ToString().Equals("fr-FR"))
            {
                className = "ClassFrLang";
            }
        }

        if (className.Equals("ClassEnLang"))
            dict = MultiligualApplication.ClassEnLang.dictionary;
        else if (className.ToString().Equals("ClassFrLang"))
        {
            dict = MultiligualApplication.ClassFrLang.dictionary;
        }
     %>


        <table style="width:100%;">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLanguage" runat="server" 
                        onselectedindexchanged="ddlLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                        AutoPostBack="True">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="en-US">English</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="fr-FR">French</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><%=dict["loginhere"] %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%=dict["userid"] %></td>
                <td>
                    <input id="txtUserId" type="text" runat="server" placeholder="<%= dict['userid']%>"/></td>
                <td>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%=dict["password"]%></td>
                <td>
                    <input id="txtPassword" type="text" runat="server" placeholder="<%= dict['password']%>"/></td>
                <td>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblErrorMsg" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="btnLogin" type="submit" value="<%= dict["submit"]%>" runat="server"/></td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Login.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MultiligualApplication
{
    public partial class LoginForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                Session["lang"] = "en-US";
            }
        }

        protected void ddlLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["lang"] = ddlLanguage.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

one of English Class file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MultiligualApplication
{
    public class ClassEnLang
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        static ClassEnLang()
        {
            dictionary.Add("loginhere", "Login Here");
            dictionary.Add("userid", "User Id");
            dictionary.Add("password", "Password");
            dictionary.Add("submit", "Submit");
        }
    }
}
```

now I am getting issue when <%=dict["submit"]%> and "dict" value inside placeholder of textbox is set. It is not showing the proper value. Is am I missing something or I am using some wrong inline tag to fetch the value. Please guide.

Comment: why you don't use built in localization mechanism? based on resx files. Samples can be found here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: Sure I will try, but can you please help me to set the value inside placeholder using current code ?

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov how I will set the placeholder value using globalization as I will set the value only for text field using this right? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov I have start working using the Globalisation but it is still showing any effect if want then I will share code also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I remember you can't use <% %> tags in server side controls.

So, you can go with approach suggested by Bhavesh Kachhadiya and remove runat attribute, or you can update them on server side.
Html code sample:

```
<input id="txtUserId" type="button" value="button" runat="server" />
```

Server side code sample:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // init this dict variable before
    txtUserId.Attributes["placeholder"] = dict["userid"];
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
      Session["lang"] = "en-US";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Getting issues because of following :

Use your tag without `runat="server"` attribute

**Use this code**

```
<input id="txtPassword" type="text" placeholder="<%= dict['password']%>"/>
```

**Instead of**

```
<input id="txtPassword" type="text" runat="server" placeholder="<%= dict['password']%>"/>
```

Comment: thanks @Bhavesh Kachhadiya but I am using this textbox value for further use. Will it be possible to keep both things? i.e. use of textbox value and placeolder ?

Comment: How? by posting form ?

Comment: Can you please explain me what exactly happening when I am using the runat tag with textbox? Once I remove this its working perfectly fine :)

Comment: when you remove runat tag, then this server is just html text. It wont be created as server side control. So you can't access to it on server side code. But you can access to value of POST data that come to server like Request["txtPassword"]

Comment: Yes by on code behind you can get value of input by `Request.Form["txtPassword"]` method